# ASP.Net /IIS Automatic Site Creation

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am looking for some open source ASP.net script that basically creates an IIS site automatically. Basically a user will enter the domain name they want (myname.mysite.com [it will always be a subdomain of mysite.com])  they would pick a username and password, and enter some other contact information. I would also add some other options that are specific to our program but these will be coded later and are not important to this question. Once they click submit it would create the Databases, DNS, create default pages, set permissions to those pages, etc.. Has anyone seen anything that can do this or would I need to create something like this from the ground up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Microsoft.Web.Administration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) as in [this blogpost](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/dennis/archive/2008/05/16/programmatically-creating-an-iis7-site.aspx)

Or you can use [System.DirectoryServices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.aspx) as shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)